# Mysql, How do i query to get name from database on base of string as input?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column **name** in my table. Which have value **Fresh Cream** for example.

And input string have value like ***This product is made of fresh cream and it is fresh made.***

I have tried using regular expression by splitting the string on base of string like

```
    Select * From products where product_name REGEXP ('[[:<:]]This[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]product[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]made[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]of[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]fresh[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]cream[[:>:]]')
```

But in this case it is also getting the records with the value **Chicken with cream**. But I want exact match of **Fresh cream**.

Is there a way to use locate() function like that,

```
    Select * from products where locate(poducts.product_name , 'This product is made of fresh cream and it is fresh made')>0
```

Or something like That

Comment: Can't you use LIKE for this?

Comment: `"Select * from products where product_name like '%fresh cream%"`

Comment: But i don't have exact word i have a string in which multiple names  could be there

Comment: CONCAT a `%` before and after your product_name column value, and then use LIKE to compare with the static search input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all the 'name' then check if your input contain one of those. Then you can use "LIKE % %" expression

```
list_of_name = SELECT product_name FROM products;
input = "This product is made of fresh cream and it is fresh made.";
foreach (list_of_name as name){
    if (strpos(input, name) !== false){
        matched_name = name;
        break;
    }
expr = "%" . matched_name . "%";
product = SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE expr;
}
```

Comment: What if product table have a large number of data? Will it cause speed or any other issue in this case?

Comment: I don't think so, the only data we iterate here is "name" which are strings, I don't think that you have more than 100.000 names in your tables?, it take less then 1s to iterate through a few hundred thousands strings so..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking this. Or I'm missing something. But shouldn't this work (and be a lot faster than REGEXP):

```
WHERE product_name LIKE '%fresh cream%'
```

That will get all records that contain `fresh cream` exactly and any preceding or following string.

Comment: Any source for the speed claim?

Comment: @Script47 REGEXP can never use an index while LIKE can.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i have long string value. How could i get this name from this string. As i don't even know this name exist in the input or not

Comment: @Kaleem, in that case. `LOCATE()` is one option or you can move some logic to your scripting language and pick out the right word from the sentence before using it in a query.

Comment: @Kaleem, there is no `fast` way of doing what you want to do in MySQL alone. I suggest you get all the `product_name` first then pick it out from the sentence.

Comment: @majid Yes i am using this already but i was thinking if there could be faster way than thi. BTW thanks man